# How to calculating values that occurred three months prior to a given date along with beginning of month data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

sample dataset:

```
Date,value
28-12-2022,10
31-01-2023,32
30-10-2023,33
30-11-2023,32
30-12-2023,31
31-01-2024,01
29-02-2024,02
```

When the date value is set as 31-01-2024, the system should display the values from three months prior, including the beginning of the month.

Expected output: For input date 31-01-2024

```
Date,value
31-01-2023,32
30-10-2023,33
```

Could someone kindly provide guidance on crafting an SQL query that can effectively calculate values in accordance with this specific scenario?

Despite my attempts to calculate it using month and year of date, the obtained results are inaccurate.

```
Declare date1 date= '31-01-2024'

select * from table where MONTH(date1) = 3 AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(date1) - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use date intervals, not functions. `DATEFROMPARTS` will calculate the beginning of the year, and `EOMONTH` can calculate the end of a particular month.

```sql
DECLARE @date1 date = '20240131';

SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(EOMONTH(@date1, -3)), 1, 1)
  AND t.Date <= EOMONTH(@date1, -3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It will be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE DATETRUNC(month,Date) <= DATETRUNC(month, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, '31-03-2024'))
      AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, '31-03-2024'))
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BWgpZKJT)

Comment: The query will encompass the values for 2022, however, it is necessary to calculate the values specifically for the period from January 2023 to three months prior to January 2024.

Comment: Can you check my recent edit

Comment: If the given date is 2024-03-31, it shall omit the data from January 2023.

Comment: What should be the expected data when the given date is `2024-03-31` ?

Comment: it should show the values from Jan 23 to Dec 2023

Comment: Included my scenrio in description

Comment: Can you check my last edit

Comment: Am getting this exception-'DATE_TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.
in ssms

Comment: its `DATETRUNC` not `DATE_TRUNC`